# при закрытии окна выбора папки закрывается родительский диалог

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

Доброе время суток!

Делаю приложение на winapi, состоящее всего из двух диалогов: основной (главное окно приложения) и модальный к нему диалог (настройки приложения).

В форме **модального** диалога есть кнопка выбора папки (реализована через функцию SHBrowseForFolder). При нажатии кнопки благополучно открывается системное окно выбора папки.

Но после любого действия (нажатие ОК, Отмена или крестик в меню) закрывается не только окно выбора папки, **но и модальное окно**, и я попадаю в основное окно приложения.

Побороть глюк пока не смог. Прошу помощи!

Если это важно, использую CodeBlocks + gcc.

```
    #include <exception>      // std::exception
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <commctrl.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <shlobj.h> // for choose folder dialog
    #include "resource.h"
    using namespace std;

    // variables for settings and shooting
    int exposure = 300, repeat = 20, comport = 1, mirror = 5, pause = 30, dither_distance = 4, eos = 0;
    bool dither_bool = false;
    //string download_to = "C:\\";
    char download_to[256] = "C:\\";

    HINSTANCE hInst;

    std::string BrowseFolder()
    {
        TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];

        BROWSEINFO bi = { 0 };
        bi.hwndOwner  =  GetActiveWindow();
        bi.lpszTitle  = ("Choose a folder to download images from camera...");
        bi.ulFlags    = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE;

        LPITEMIDLIST pidl = SHBrowseForFolder ( &bi );

        if ( pidl != 0 )
        {
            //get the name of the folder and put it in path
            SHGetPathFromIDList ( pidl, path );

            //free memory used
            IMalloc * imalloc = 0;
            if ( SUCCEEDED( SHGetMalloc ( &imalloc )) )
            {
                imalloc->Free ( pidl );
                imalloc->Release ( );
            }

            return path;
        }
        return "";
    }

    void SaveSettings()
    // save settings to ts.cfg
    {
        ofstream config_file ("ts.cfg", ios::out | ios::trunc);
        config_file << "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE! USE SETTINGS BUTTON IN APPLICATION" << endl;
        config_file << comport << endl;
        config_file << mirror << endl;
        config_file << pause << endl;
        config_file << dither_distance << endl;
        config_file << eos << endl;
        config_file << download_to << endl;
        config_file.close();
    }

    void LoadSettings()
    {
        // check ts.cfg and read from it
        ifstream config_file("ts.cfg");
        try
        {
            string s;
            getline(config_file,s);
            getline(config_file,s);
            comport = stoi(s);
            getline(config_file,s);
            mirror = stoi(s);
            getline(config_file,s);
            pause = stoi(s);
            getline(config_file,s);
            dither_distance = stoi(s);
            getline(config_file,s);
            eos = stoi(s);
            // in case of error with stoi(), exception will be thrown automatically
            // but with the next line we have to throw it manually:
            if (getline(config_file,s))
            {
                strcpy (download_to,s.c_str());
            }
            else
            {
                throw(1);
            }
            config_file.close();
        }
        catch (...)
            // we don't find ts.cfg or it has errors
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,"Configuration file is missing or corrupted. Defaults will be used. Check settings.","TinyShooter",MB_ICONWARNING);
            SaveSettings();
        }
    }

    BOOL CALLBACK DlgSettings(HWND hwndDlg,
                              UINT message,
                              WPARAM wParam,
                              LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            // set icon
            HICON hIcon;
            hIcon = (HICON)LoadImageW(GetModuleHandleW(NULL),
                                      MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDI_ICON1),
                                      IMAGE_ICON,
                                      GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
                                      GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
                                      0);
            if (hIcon)
            {
                SendMessage(hwndDlg, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIcon);
            }
            // real code here
            LoadSettings();
            // set values to dialog from ts.cfg
            SetDlgItemInt(hwndDlg,ID_COM,comport,false);
            SetDlgItemInt(hwndDlg,ID_MIRROR,mirror,false);
            SetDlgItemInt(hwndDlg,ID_PAUSE,pause,false);
            SetDlgItemInt(hwndDlg,ID_DITHER,dither_distance,false);
            SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg,ID_PATH,download_to);
            if (eos == 1)
            {
                CheckDlgButton(hwndDlg,ID_DOWNLOAD,BST_CHECKED);
            }
            else
            {
                CheckDlgButton(hwndDlg,ID_DOWNLOAD,BST_UNCHECKED);
            }

        }
        return TRUE;



        return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
            case ID_PATH_BUTTON:
            {
                // choose path to download images here
                strcpy (download_to,BrowseFolder().c_str());
            }
            case IDOK:
            {
                // save settings herehwndDlg
                BOOL bSuccess;
                comport = GetDlgItemInt(hwndDlg,ID_COM,&bSuccess,false);
                mirror = GetDlgItemInt(hwndDlg,ID_MIRROR,&bSuccess,false);
                pause = GetDlgItemInt(hwndDlg,ID_PAUSE,&bSuccess,false);
                dither_distance = GetDlgItemInt(hwndDlg,ID_DITHER,&bSuccess,false);
                if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hwndDlg,ID_DOWNLOAD) == BST_CHECKED)
                {
                    eos = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    eos = 0;
                }

                GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, ID_PATH, download_to, 256);
                //MessageBox(hwndDlg,msg,"info",1);
                //download_to = msg;

                SaveSettings();
            }

            case IDCANCEL:
                EndDialog(hwndDlg, wParam);
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    BOOL CALLBACK DlgMain(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch(uMsg)
        {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            // set icon
            HICON hIcon;
            hIcon = (HICON)LoadImageW(GetModuleHandleW(NULL),
                                      MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDI_ICON1),
                                      IMAGE_ICON,
                                      GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
                                      GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
                                      0);
            if (hIcon)
            {
                SendMessage(hwndDlg, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIcon);
            }

            // set default values to exporuse and frames
            SetDlgItemInt(hwndDlg,ID_EXP,exposure,false);
            SetDlgItemInt(hwndDlg,ID_COUNT,repeat,false);
            // parse config :)
            LoadSettings();

        }
        return TRUE;

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
        }
        return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
            // open settings dialog
            case 4:
            {
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG_SETTINGS),  hwndDlg, (DLGPROC)DlgSettings);
            }
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
    {
        hInst=hInstance;
        InitCommonControls();
        return DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgMain);
    }
```

Comment: Вы словили в диалоге, который открыл окно выбора каталога, IDCANCEL, которая вызвала EndDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В секции

```
case ID_PATH_BUTTON:
```

не хватает `break`

т.е. должно выглядеть вот так:

```
case ID_PATH_BUTTON:
{
  // choose path to download images here
  strcpy (download_to,BrowseFolder().c_str());
  break;
}
```

В противном случае, выполнение программы, после закрытия диалога пойдет в следующий `case` и, соответственно, вызовет `EndDialog`

Не забывайте `break` в операторах `switch/case`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я перерыл все интернеты в поисках ошибки, а она была на поверхности...

Comment: @AntonVakulenko не за что. Если ответ правильный, то пометьте его, как принятый